# Tell me what is actually broken

Tags: broken-screen

I got a Galaxy S4, which was accidently fallen by me on floor, not it won't show anything on screen and appers to be broken motherboard or screen, can anyone tell me what is actually broken either of these. When I connect it to my PC it shows me as Removable Drive, but when i try attempt to go on Odin mode by I just dit earlier by pulling battery and holding power+home+volume up. It just shows me as 'ID : COM5' in odin. Can anyone please tell wheather screen i broken or motherboard? Please I need help.
Regards, 
Dc5000gs4

Comment: Odin mode is Volume Down + Home + Power then volume up to confirm. And it is very difficult to guess what can be broken inside. You should take it to a repair shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see it as a removable device and Odin connects, there is a fairly good, but not 100% chance, that the internals are okay.

If you want complete confirmation, buy a HDMI output cable for your phone and plug it into a TV (Research your device to find exactly how your it works with this system). You should see the screen, however, this is, in my mind, overkill. Send it to a repair shop an they'll have a better idea of what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have a rooted device, can there any change to take screen on computer as I have Mobile for Samsung installed.